# What exactly is incremental about git blame --incremental?

Tags: git, git-blame

The docs state:

--incremental
       Show the result incrementally in a format designed for machine consumption.

But looking at the output I don't see anything more than it being a summary without the actual lines of the files.

How does --incremental actually differ from -p?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-blame.html :

> -p
>   --porcelain Show in a format designed for machine consumption.
>
> --incremental Show the result incrementally in a format designed for machine consumption.

[I found this comment from Junio and have the difference **bolded**](http://www.gelato.unsw.edu.au/archives/git/0701/38327.html):

> When called with `--incremental` option, the command outputs the
>   result as it is built.  The output generally will talk about lines
>   touched by more recent commits first and is meant to be used by
>   interactive viewers.
>
> **The output format is similar to the Porcelain format, but it does not
>   contain the actual lines from the file that is being annotated**.